# Locally finitely generated sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

[Here is the image from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dJce.png)

So I don't quite understand the proof of lemma 3.9. Namely, I don't see why there exists $H_{jk}$ such that the formula is true on $U'$. I was wondering if someone could explain to me. Thanks. BTW this is from Demailly's book on Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry.

Answer (score 2):

For any $f\in \mathcal{G}(\Omega)$ where $x_0\in \Omega$. We have $f|_{x_0}=a_{1,x_0}G_{1}|_{x_0}+...a_{N,x_0}G_{N}|_{x_0}$ where $a_{i,x_0}\in \mathcal{A}_{x_0}$ and $G_{i}|_{x_0}$ is the restriction of $G_i$ at point $x_0$ since $G_{i}|_{x_0}$ spans $\mathcal{G}_{x_0}$.

On the other hand, for any $a_{x_0}\in  \mathcal{A}_{x_0}$, we know there is an open set $x_0\in U_i$ such that there exists $a\in \mathcal{A}(U_i)$ and $a|_{x_0}=a_{x_0}$. That's the definiton of stalk which is $$\mathcal{A}_{x_0}=\lim_{\underset{x_0\in U}{\rightarrow}}\mathcal{A}(U)$$.

Let $U=\cap_{i=1}^{N}U_i$ which contains $x_0$ of course. Then $f_|{x_0}=(a_1G_1+a_2G_2+...+a_NG_{N})_|{x_0}$. Here $a_1G_1+a_2G_2+...+a_NG_{N}\in \mathcal{G}(U)$.

Then by the definition of stalk again, there is an open set $\Omega'\subset U$ such that $f|_{\Omega'}=(a_1G_1+a_2G_2+...+a_NG_{N})|_{\Omega'}={a_1}_{|_{\Omega'}}G_1+...+{a_N}_{|_{\Omega'}}G_{N}$.

If we take $f=F_i$ and ${a_j}_{\Omega'}=H_{ij}$. Then $F_i=\sum_{j}H_{ij} G_{j}$.